# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Still on learning ionic together with mysql and trying to create a login form with remote database, facing a problem that i got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

Below is my code

login.html

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
  <h1 class="title">Onseral</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class="padding has-header">
    <ion-list>
       <ion-item>
         <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
         <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>

     <button nav-clear class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="LogIn()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('ionicApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 })

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $ionicPopup) {
  $scope.LogIn = function() {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/api/login.php",
        data: {
          username: $scope.username,
          password: $scope.password
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      });

      /*Successful HTTP post request or not */

      request.success(function (data){

        if (data == '1'){
          console.log('test success');
          }
         else {
         console.log('test failed');
         console.log($scope.username);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

app.js

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','ionicApp.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $stateProvider

.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

    .state('login', {
     url: "/login",
     templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
     controller: 'LoginCtrl'
 });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

It just cant get the username from the login.html, what am i missing here?

Comment: Where in your code does it throw the error?

Comment: console.log($scope.username);

Comment: So you mean that `$scope` is undefined on that line? That would be really weird

Comment: yes. it should log the user that i have typed in login form, right? it gave an undefined status in console log

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see your ng-controller anywhere written in the code.

your ng-model is binded to the controller you use and hence as there is no any controller in your view the value of the username in your controller is undefined.

Comment: sorry, i have includ the controller file.

Comment: can we add cordova things to plunkr?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea about it. As per I know all javascript libraries can be included. Else you just add some more detailed code here from the conrtollers I think that would help to check your issue

Comment: i can add any other js files, but i cant seem to be able to find that cordova.js in my project, weird.

Comment: Else you just add some more detailed code here from the conrtollers I think that would help to check your issue –

Comment: Hmmm, thats all controllers files i have, i have posted it above.

Comment: Hi @JosephGoh I have created a basic plunkr for you based on your code which works fine for me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/msgwzckPqRerLm70lzvM?p=preview

only thing is I have not created it through a stateprovider but code would be the same